# Getting TypeError: execve() arg 3 contains a non-string value when trying to run nodejs in sublime text

Tags: python, sublimetext

I am trying to run javascript with sublime text through nodejs plugin, and been getting the following message. I've found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13213676/165820) that seems to be relevant but I still couldn't figure it out. The script is encoded by UTF-8. Thank you.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
  File "./lib/command_thread.py", line 41, in run
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 623, in __init__
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1141, in _execute_child
TypeError: execve() arg 3 contains a non-string value
```

ps. I am running OS X (10.8).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it was fixed by putting this in my Nodejs.sublime-settings file (accessible by hitting command+shift+p and selecting Nodejs::User File Settings):

```
{
    "node_path": "/opt/local/lib/",
    "node_command": "/opt/local/bin/node"
}
```

Replace the paths with something that makes sense on your system.